# How can I edit the font size in linePlotImageDisplay

Tags: plot, dm-script

Here is my code to generate a simple sine function. How can I manipulate the font size of X/Y-axis labels and ticks in the linePlotImageDisplay.?

```
Number N = 360, phase =60*pi()/180
image sine := RealImage("Sine Pattern", 4, N, 1)
sine = cos(4*pi()*(icol/N)-phase)
setDisplayType(sine, 4)
sine.ImageSetDimensionUnitString(0, "Angle (degree)" )
sine.ImageSetIntensityUnitString("Radius (pixels)" )
linePlotImageDisplay lpid = sine.imageGetImageDisplay(0)
lpid.linePlotImageDisplaySetDoAutoSurvey(0,0)
showImage(sine)
```

[sine function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/curs3.png)

Answer (score 1):

The commands you're looking for are only available in newer GMS versions, and they are only documented since GMS 3. They are:

`void LinePlotImageDisplaySetFontSize( LinePlotImageDisplay lpid, Number size )`

`void LinePlotImageDisplaySetFontFamily( LinePlotImageDisplay lpid, string familyName )`

`void LinePlotImageDisplaySetFontAttributes( LinePlotImageDisplay lpid, number bold, number style )`

`void LinePlotImageDisplaySetFontColor( LinePlotImageDisplay lpid, number r, number g, number b )`

and the according `Get...` commands as described in the F1 help documentation (of recent GMS versions) at:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I have figured it out.